# passing an extra parameter in jobschedule in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any possible way to pass any extra parameter instead of `date` in  `schedule.scheduleJob(date,function(id))`

The below code is not working

```
var id =record.id;
  var date =record.date;


    jobsCollection.save({
     id: record.id
 }, {
     $set: record
 }, function (err, result) {
     var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function (id) {
         return function () {
             console.log("inside----------")
             console.log(id)
         };

     }(id));
     if (!err) {
         return context.sendJson([], 404);;
     }


 });
```

i want to pass the date along with another data to schedule jobs. so that i can perform other operations based on the `date schedul`e and that `id`

Comment: How are you populating "mydata"? Is it global?

Comment: You can just use it in the call back function right?

Comment: Can you brief me about wat you are actually trying to do

Comment: ok,what i want is i have a database with values datetime,id,and other values .....after saving the details to database i have to call a schedulejob function so that i can fetch the details on the basis of id(coz id is unique) and show that details based on the data scheduled.i have upldated my question.please check it also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`schedule.scheduleJob()` accepts three parameters.So you can pass `id` as one of the parameter

```
var id =record.id;
  var date =record.date;


jobsCollection.save({
 id: record.id
 }, {
     $set: record
 }, function (err, result) {
     var j = schedule.scheduleJob(id,date, function () {
        console.log(id) //this will prints your id

     });
     if (!err) {
         return context.sendJson([], 404);;
     }


 });
```